# Restore RGB Values from Luminance Value?

Tags: image-processing, color

I am not sure, but can we get RGB (Red-Green-Blue) values from calculated luminance value for each pixel?

`L = R_irradiance*.265 + G_irradiance*.67 + B_irradiance*.065`

Comment: Do you have enough information to validate an answer?

Answer (score 3):

No, because luminance is a weighted sum of RGB components and has no color information, so it is greyscale only.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly and simply, because you cannot retrieve three values from their (weighted) sum without additional information.

However, there is a topic called [colour recovery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_recovery) or [image colorization](https://richzhang.github.io/colorization/). It aims at retrieving meaningful colors from grayscale images. The following picture comes from [Colorful Image Colorization](https://richzhang.github.io/colorization/) (Richard Zhang, Phillip Isola, Alexei A. Efros):

[image: Colorful Image Colorization]

A recent paper is: [Luminance-Chrominance Model for Image Colorization](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01051308/document):

> This paper provides a new method to colorize gray-scale images. While
>   the reverse operation is only a matter of standard, the colorization
>   process is an ill-posed problem that requires some priors. In the
>   literature two classes of approach exist. The first class includes
>   manual methods that needs the user to manually add colors on the image
>   to colorize. The second class includes exemplar-based approaches where
>   a color image, with a similar semantic content, is provided as input
>   to the method. These two types of priors have their own advantages and
>   drawbacks. In this paper, a new variational framework for
>   exemplar-based colorization is proposed. A nonlocal approach is used
>   to find relevant color in the source image in order to suggest colors
>   on the gray-scale image. The spatial coherency of the result as well
>   as the final color selection is provided by a non-convex variational
>   framework based on a total variation. An efficient primal-dual
>   algorithm is provided and a proof of its convergence is proposed. In
>   this work, we also extend the proposed exemplar-based approach to
>   combine both exemplar-based and manual methods. It provides a single
>   framework that unifies advantages of both approaches. Finally,
>   experiments and comparisons with state-of-the-art methods illustrate
>   the efficiency of our method